# Developing applications for Nokia 5310

Tags: java-me, sms, nokia

EDIT:

Is there any other phone systems that allow connecting into the native messaging system to read input in the composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no way to do this in standard J2ME.

Symbian phones will allow you to write C++ code that comes close to doing what you describe.

You may not be able to directly query the text editor GUI control for its content but you can create your own messaging module and have your own message editor or you can read messages in the draft and outbox folders of the local store.

Answer (score 0):

5310 is Series 40 based so I would assume that you can't capture input from the native messaging composer. The S40 platform is fairly closed.